# airbrake notify_airbrake method not working in controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, exception, airbrake

In airbrake controller this code works (gives notification)
rescue => ex
Airbrake.notify
but

```
rescue => ex
    notify_airbrake(ex)
end
```

Doesn't give a any airbrake notification.how to make
notify_airbrake(ex) to work

Answer (score 3):

You're probably testing that in your development environment. Add this to your `airbrake.rb` and it should work.

`config.development_environments = []`

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `notify_airbrake` ignores local request. So if you try to use this method in development you're out of luck. No matter what you've defined in your Airbrake config.

So you could set `consider_all_requests_local = false`, which is properly not what you want.

Instead you can use `airbrake_request_data` to get the same result if you don't want to pick the params by yourself.

```
rescue => ex
  Airbrake.notify(ex, airbrake_request_data)
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it matters, `notify_airbrake` checks if the current environment is inside `Airbrake::Configuration.development_environments`. if you put `development_environments` to empty array, it will send the notification no matter what. we have also changed the implementation of `Airbrake::ControllerMethods#notify_airbrake` to check for ignored agents. That will be released in *3.1.7*.